# How to calculate average value from an ArrayList

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate the average value from a shopping cart (ArrayList). Average value means the sum all the products divided by its quantity?, correct me If I am wrong please maybe that's why my logic is not working well.

I was trying to do a loop for calculating the sum of all the products and then divided by its quantity.

```
public double getAverageValue(){
    double averageValue = 0;

    for ( int i=0; i < cartLineList.size() ; i++) {
        double sum += cartLineList.get(i).getProduct();
    }

    for (CartLine cart : cartLineList) {
        averageValue = (sum / cart.getQuantity());
    }
    return averageValue;
}

public class CartLine {

private Product product;
private int quantity;

public CartLine(Product product, int quantity) {
    this.product = product;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public double getSubtotal() {
    return quantity * product.getPrice();
}

public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
}
```

Comment: It seems fine, what is your problem?

Comment: Doesn't even compile. `sum` is scoped only for the first loop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359907/array-sum-and-average look for the correct way here. Your code doesn't seem to compile. What you should look for is to define ```sum``` variable first and only once (cause right now you're doing it every loop), then accumulate the sum and in the end divide sum by the size of the cart array.

Comment: @НикитаМихайлов keep in mind that java != javascript

Comment: I guess getProduct dont return a double but a product. Don't you have a getPrice() method or somethng like that? "=+" is not valid. Last "+=" is not necessary. Division should be done with BigDecimal to avoid issues

Comment: @Lino didn't even notice that, thanks. However since this is more of an algorithmic problem this should be helpful anyway.

Comment: It seams your logic is not clear, Do you want like `sum of all product divided by sum of quantity`

Comment: Could you please share the structure of `CartLine` class

Comment: Show an example input and desired output.

Comment: @alain.janinm `=+` is valid, but more like `= +` that is, assignment and [Unary Plus Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3) (mostly NOP just numeric promotion, sure not what is wanted)

Comment: @DKAnsh I m trying to get the average value from a cart. Therefore I want all the products price from that cart and then divided by its quantity. Something like this ( I got 3 products in a cart of 15$, 20 and 10$ then the AVG will be 45$/3 = 15$) I dont know if that makes sense for you.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Indeed your right. I said it's not valid because it should be used with primitive numeric. I doubt that its the return type of getProduct(). And honestly I don't think that he wants to use the unary plus operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
public double getAverageValue(){
  double averageValue = 0;
  double sum = 0;

  if(cartLineList.size() > 0){
    for ( int i=0; i < cartLineList.size() ; i++) {
      // assuming the product class has a price
      sum += cartLineList.get(i).getProduct().getPrice();
    }
    averageValue = (sum / (double)cartLineList.size())
  }

  return averageValue;
}
```

Comment: ```if(cartLineList.size() > 0)``` is redunant though, as well as casting size of the ```cartLineList``` to double since ```sum``` is already double.

Comment: No you need to check if its more than 0 when you divide by it `averageValue = (sum / (double)cartLineList.size())`. Also when you divide or multiply between a double a non double value you should always convert both to double, or else you get weird results.

Comment: Sorry, didn't pay enough attention, you're right about checking for the zero, however, it might be better to use ```isEmpty()``` method. I've never heard of some issues with dividing double by integer. Can you share some topics about it?

Comment: Thank you @HarisBouchlis! It compiles but when I run JUnit Test didn't work but after debugging all good as I corrected the expected value from this function.

Comment: @Никита Михайлов check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571909/java-integer-double-division-confusion?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @HarisBouchlis but it is wrong that you need to convert **both** values to double - where is that documented? in contrast to [JLS 5.6.2 - Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) (the posted link is about both values being **int**)